# ccpDistance() function in cocos2D android

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am working on a game in Cocos2D android.
I found that some of the functions are missing in android cocos2D like ccpDistance(), ccpMidpoint() etc. where can I get the library for these?

Answer (score 1):

Inside Cocos2d-android library you will get CGPoint.java class.its will